# Javascript,To add text to element which has a exsisting text-node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add a text next to "Groceries" in the `<h1>` tag using either `nodeValue` property or `textContentPropery`. I have added two methods that are not working for me.Give me a reason why is it not happening not just the answer.
I don't want to use `appendChild` property in this.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="head">Groceries</h1
    ><div id="li-container"
        ><ul
        ><li>item2</li
        ><li>item3</li
        ><li>item4</li
        ><li>item5</li  
        ></ul
    ></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    var head = document.getElementById("head").firstChild.nodeValue;
    head.nodeValue = head + list.length;

    //OR OR OR OR 
    //
    var head = document.getElementById("head").firstChild.textContent;
    head.textContent = head + list.length;

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var head = document.getElementById("head").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Here head contains only the text `Groceries`. So you can't access `groceries`.nodevalue

So you must use:

```
var head = document.getElementById("head").firstChild;
head.textContent = head.nodeValue + list.length;
```

Here, we're storing the reference of the textNode in `head` at first.

In second line, we are setting the textContent in that textNode.

Comment: when should `head.firstChild.nodeValue` be used.In other example/code.

Comment: In terms of textNode, both nodeValue and textContent will return you same value. Just while you are doing string concatenation, you must use textNode.nodeValue. But in your both examples, you've used it before itself while referencing the element. That's the reason why string.nodeValue/string.textContent doesn't exist so you're not getting the desired output

Answer (score 1):

In your case `head` is a string value as you are assigning the [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) of the header element to it, but any changes does to the variable value will not get reflected in the header as the string is not a mutable object.

You need to refer to the text node element and set its node value

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var head = document.getElementById("head").firstChild;
console.log(head)
head.nodeValue = head.nodeValue + list.length;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1do9wrw7/)

Comment: can we use `textContent` to change ?